# How do I write a analyzable thread dump format

Tags: java, formatting, multithreading, analysis, dump

I'm creating a global exception handling which collects some information before shutting down in some cases. One of this information is the current thread dump. i do this with following code:

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true);
```

The problem is to write the information into a analyzable format for TDA. Is there a "simple" way to format the information instead of writing the format on my own?

EDIT: I'd like to have a full thread dump so I can find problematic threads. The above mentioned method delivers an array of ThreadInfo-Objects, so i have the data. My problem is that the written output isn't in a format TDA recognizes as thread dump.

Comment: What kind of format would like to have ? And what does ThreadMXBean provides ?

Comment: What is this TDA you speak of?

Comment: I think it's this, right? https://tda.dev.java.net/

Comment: Yes, https://tda.dev.java.net is the TDA I speak of

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to copy the TDA code (It is LGPL, after all) you can also use the Attach API to get data in the standard format. As far as I know, the only JVM built-in code to do the dump is native code in the Attach agent.

```
String selfName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
final int selfPid = Integer.valueOf(selfName.substring(0, selfName.indexOf('@')));                

HotSpotVirtualMachine vm = (HotSpotVirtualMachine) VirtualMachine.attach(Integer.toString(selfPid));

InputStream sDump = vm.remoteDataDump(new Object[]{"-l"}); // lowercase L for lock dump
```

The data dump will return the dump in a stream of character data.

Comment: Nice one. Needs dropped access restrictions in Eclipse to resolve the com.sun classes though.

Comment: Just to add... HotSpotVirtualMachine.class is only available in 1.6 or later ,within the JDK's tools.jar

Answer (score 1):

Just use the code TDA uses itself to dump JMX-data: [MBeanDumper.java](https://tda.dev.java.net/source/browse/*checkout*/tda/tda/src/java/com/pironet/tda/jconsole/MBeanDumper.java?rev=1.16)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, then bwithers has [described](http://bwithers.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/schedule-your-own-java-thread-dumps/) a way to signal the JVM to thread dump.

There's also a [pure java approach](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm), but I'm not sure that the output is in standard format.